# localtime() doesn't return the correct value

Tags: c, time

I have a problem with **localtime()**. The scope is to transform my own **struct tbDate** to **struct tm**.
Since the simple assignment doesn't fill the follow arguments:

```
tmp->tm_wday;
tmp->tm_yday;
tmp->tm_year;
```

that I need, since I have my own implementation of **strftime()** So, I fill a **struct tm** with my own data, I call **mktime()** to get the secunds, than I call **localtime()** to get a **struct tm** filled, and than I fill my **struct tm**.

```
int tbDate_to_tm(tbDate *date,struct tm *syst)
{
    time_t t;

    struct tm *tmp;
    syst->tm_hour=0;
    syst->tm_min=0;
    syst->tm_sec=0;
    syst->tm_year=date->year-1900;
    syst->tm_mon=date->month-1;
    syst->tm_mday=date->day;
    
    t=mktime(syst);
    tmp=localtime(&t);
    
    syst->tm_hour=tmp->tm_hour;
    syst->tm_isdst=tmp->tm_isdst;
    syst->tm_mday=tmp->tm_mday;
    syst->tm_min=tmp->tm_min;
    syst->tm_mon=tmp->tm_mon;
    syst->tm_sec=tmp->tm_sec;
    syst->tm_wday=tmp->tm_wday;
    syst->tm_yday=tmp->tm_yday;
    syst->tm_year=tmp->tm_year;


    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that returns the date of the day before, rather than the correct date.
The system is Windows, and the compiler mingw.
Someone can notice something wrong?
Example:

```
date->year=2022;
date->month=11;
date->day=1;
//these settings returns a time_t t
t=1667253600;
//after I call localtime()
tmp->tm_hour=23;
tmp->tm_isdst=0;
tmp->tm_mday=31;
tmp->tm_min=0;
tmp->tm_mon=9;
tmp->tm_sec=0;
tmp->tm_wday=1;
tmp->tm_yday=303;
tmp->tm_year=122;
```

rather than:

```
tmp->tm_hour=0;
tmp->tm_isdst=0;
tmp->tm_mday=1;
tmp->tm_min=0;
tmp->tm_mon=10;
tmp->tm_sec=0;
tmp->tm_wday=2;
tmp->tm_yday=304;
tmp->tm_year=122;
```

Comment: What are the `tm_hour`, `tm_min` and `tm_sec` values in your result?  A few seconds before midnight?  If so, the calculation is probably missing a handful of leap seconds, and since your input hour, minute, and second are all zero you wind up with the day before.

Comment: Nothing you post *shows* what you mean. Provide input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, these values are correctly setted to 0

Comment: @SanPei what output do you get and what output do you expect? Please [edit] your question and make that clear.

Comment: I edited.
@Andrew Henle I was wrong, hour is 23 instead then 0

Comment: Can you please construct a minimal complete program to demonstrate. Something we can compile and run. Right now, you're showing fragments of a program, and from this example it's hard to know if you're even using pointers correctly. We just have to take your word for it.

Comment: You have *overwritten* members of `*syst` passed *except* `tm_isdst`.

Comment: @Wather Vane I checked tm_isdst, I set it to -1 and it works, thanks for the hint

Comment: This smells like an issue with time zones.  What do you expect to achieve by calling `localtime()` that you could not achieve at least as easily by reading out the updates that `mktime()` applies to the `struct tm` you pass to it?  You seem to be doing more work than is needed.

Comment: @SanPei does "it works" mean that you solved the problem? Which appeared to be about DST from the off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overwritten members of `*syst` passed except `tm_isdst`.

I suggest you add one of these lines:

```
syst->tm_isdst = -1;
syst->tm_isdst = 0;
syst->tm_isdst = 1;
```

depending on your need. The MS man page for [`mktime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=msvc-170) says

> When specifying a `tm` structure time, set the `tm_isdst` field to:
>
> - Zero (0) to indicate that standard time is in effect.
> - A value greater than 0 to indicate that daylight saving time is in effect.
> - A value less than zero to have the C run-time library code compute whether standard time or daylight saving time is in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Weather Vane solved, I put **syst->tm_isdst=-1**, and now it works:

```
int tbDate_to_tm(tbDate *date,struct tm *syst)
{
    time_t t;

    struct tm *tmp;
    syst->tm_hour=0;
    syst->tm_min=0;
    syst->tm_sec=0;
    syst->tm_year=date->year-1900;
    syst->tm_mon=date->month-1;
    syst->tm_mday=date->day;
    syst->tm_isdst=-1;             // added this

    t=mktime(syst);
    tmp=localtime(&t);
    
    syst->tm_hour=tmp->tm_hour;
    syst->tm_isdst=tmp->tm_isdst;
    syst->tm_mday=tmp->tm_mday;
    syst->tm_min=tmp->tm_min;
    syst->tm_mon=tmp->tm_mon;
    syst->tm_sec=tmp->tm_sec;
    syst->tm_wday=tmp->tm_wday;
    syst->tm_yday=tmp->tm_yday;
    syst->tm_year=tmp->tm_year;


    return 1;
}
```